# Generate multiple independent random streams in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate multiple streams of random numbers in python.
I am writing a program for simulating queues system and want one stream for the inter-arrival time and another stream for the service time and so on.

`numpy.random()` generates random numbers from a global stream.

In matlab there is [something called RandStream](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html) which enables me to create multiple streams.

Is there any way to create something like RandStream in Python

Comment: Are you intending this for variance reduction purposes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both Numpy and the internal random generators have instantiatable classes.

For just `random`:

```
import random
random_generator = random.Random()
random_generator.random()
#>>> 0.9493959884174072
```

And for Numpy:

```
import numpy
random_generator = numpy.random.RandomState()
random_generator.uniform(0, 1, 10)
#>>> array([ 0.98992857,  0.83503764,  0.00337241,  0.76597264,  0.61333436,
#>>>         0.0916262 ,  0.52129459,  0.44857548,  0.86692693,  0.21150068])
```

Comment: Where do I find the docs for the first one? I cannot seem to Google it properly...

Comment: @Atcold "The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state." - https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: But how do you generate independent streams? Are successive seeds guaranteed to work?

Comment: @Praveen If you just want different streams, use `random.Random()`. If you want to seed it for reproducibility, any seeds that differ will be fine.

Comment: Any seeds that differ will not be fine. The streams will not be independent: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/01/07/a-primer-on-repeatable-random-numbers/

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida That's a pathological example, and there are a few reasons this doesn't apply here. 1) we're only generating two sequences, so the sequences will quickly decorrelate, rather than one sample from many contiguous sequences, 2) Python's seeding has a hashing step to fix up correlations, 3) you're never going to get ideal independence from a mediocre generator like a Mersenne Twister anyway; use a better RNG (preferably a cryptographic one) and don't use fixed seeds, if that's an issue. I agree that using larger higher-entropy seeds is more risk-averse.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida It's worth noting that C# seems to be using a subtractive generator, which looks garbage.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the RandomGen package. Simply initiate two streams would suffice. For example:

```
import numpy as np
prng1 = np.random.RandomState()
prng2 = np.random.RandomState()
prng1.seed(1)
prng2.seed(1)
```

Now if you progress both streams using `prngX.rand()`, you will find that the two streams will give you identical results, which means they are independent streams with the same seed.

To use the `random` package, simply swap out `np.random.RandomState()` for `random.Random()`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of reproducibility you can pass a seed directly to `random.Random()` and then call variables from there. Each initiated instance would then run independently from the other. For example, if you run:

```
import random
rg1 = random.Random(1)
rg2 = random.Random(2)
rg3 = random.Random(1)
for i in range(5): print(rg1.random())
print('')
for i in range(5): print(rg2.random())
print('')
for i in range(5): print(rg3.random())
```

You'll get:

```
0.134364244112
0.847433736937
0.763774618977
0.255069025739
0.495435087092

0.956034271889
0.947827487059
0.0565513677268
0.0848719951589
0.835498878129

0.134364244112
0.847433736937
0.763774618977
0.255069025739
0.495435087092
```

Answer (score 0):

Veedrac's answer did not address how one might generate independent streams.

The best way I could find to generate independent streams is to use a replacement for numpy's RandomState. This is provided by the [RandomGen package](https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/index.html).

It supports [independent random streams](https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/parallel.html#independent-streams), but these use one of three random number generators: PCG64, ThreeFry or Philox. If you want to use the more conventional MT19937, you can rely on [jumping](https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/parallel.html#jump-advance-the-prng-state) instead.

Comment: `random.Random()` *is* an independent stream, at least up to the limits of a Mersenne Twister. If you need `n` streams, do `[random.Random() for _ in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` added feature to generate independent streams of Random Numbers using `SeedSequence`. This process a user-provided seed, typically as an integer of some size, and to convert it into an initial state for a BitGenerator. It uses hashing techniques to ensure that low-quality seeds are turned into high quality initial states (at least, with very high probability).

```
from numpy.random import SeedSequence, default_rng

ss = SeedSequence(12345)

# Spawn off 10 child SeedSequences to pass to child processes.
child_seeds = ss.spawn(10)
streams = [default_rng(s) for s in child_seeds]
```

each stream is PCG64 generator. Random numbers can be generated sequentially as follows -

```
for i in 1:K
    instance[i] = [s.uniform() for s in streams]
```

There are more ways to generate independent streams of random numbers, check [numpydocs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html).