# How to generate independent identically distributed (iid) random variables in python

Tags: python, random, probability, probability-theory

I am developing a simulation infrastructure with some random events (for instance, sources that generate output with a certain probability). So far I've been doing it using the random.random() function. Ex:

```
class source:
    def output(self, x):
        if(random.random()<=x):
            return foo
a = []
for i in xrange(10)
    a.append(source())

for i in xrange(1000):
    for j in xrange(len(a)):
        a[j].output()
```

From what I understand, all of the sources in my list "a" will get random numbers from the same pseudo-random LFSR source, so a[0] will get a sample, then a[1] will get the next one, then a[2], etc. If random.ramdom() generated a truly random sequence, I believe this would still generate 10 iid subsets of values, however, since I am assuming that python uses an LFSR, or a similar scheme, where each subsequent sample depends on the previous sample, taking several subsets of these samples may or may not be independent and identically distributed.

I have two questions:

1. What kind of distributions do I actually get using my pseudocode or something similar to that
2. How do I get several iid random variables in python?

I looked at other stack overflow posts, like this one for example:
[Generate multiple independent random streams in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204582/generate-multiple-independent-random-streams-in-python)
but they don't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python stdlib `random` module is implemented using a a Mersenne Twister. From [the docs for `random`:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces
>   53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1.

I believe this satisfies your independence requirement. Check out [the Wikipedia article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) in particular the section on the "*k*-distribution" property.

Comment: I think it's an overkill in practice (not using Mersenne, but rather rejecting the Standard's random), however nice reference to the "k-distribution" of Mersenne.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully be clearer, what I meant was that the  **default implementation** in Python uses a Mersenne twister